# Showing $\|T_n\|$ is bounded if each $(T_nx)$ is Cauchy

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $(T_nx) \in B(X,Y)$ is Cauchy in $X$ for every $x \in X$ where $X$ is Banach space and $Y$ is normed space. I have to show that $\|T_n\|$ is bounded. I think I have to show sequence $\|T_n\|$ is also Cauchy. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\|T_n\|$ is unbounded, by the Uniform Boundedness Principle, there is some $x$ such that $(T_nx)$ is unbounded, so $(T_nx)$ can't be Cauchy.

Answer (score 3):

If $T_n(x)$ is bounded for every $x$, you can apply

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle